# Issue with ng-model changing another object's property values

Tags: javascript, angularjs, scope

I am trying to eventually compare the entries in two arrays of objects so I make an array called $scope.oitems and $scope.items that both get assigned the value returned from a data service, setItems. I have inputs that are ng-modeled to $scope.items; however, when I look at $scope.items and $scope.oitems, they both change value when I change what is in the input field. I have an object, $scope.thing, and what is supposed to be the original copy, $scope.othing, both only having 'name' and 'id' properties, both are assigned in a data service, setThing, along with $scope.name and $scope.id which are assigned DATAFROMSERVICE.name and DATAFROMSERVICE.id. $scope.othing and $scope.thing both are changed when the input only ng-modeled to $scope.thing is changed HOWEVER, $scope.name and $scope.id DO NOT CHANGE, this is what I want for $scope.othing and $scope.oitems, as these are supposed to be copies of the data returned from the service to be used later. What am I doing wrong in my assignment of othing and oitems to cause them to not be original copies of the data from my service? Here is a fiddle with the simplified example of my issue described above

http://jsfiddle.net/Lvc0u55v/1163/

```
function MyCtrl($scope) {
$scope.oitems = new Array();
$scope.othing = new Object();


function setItems () {
    var data = [{a:'foo', b:2}, {a:'bar', b: 1}]; //data returned from service
  $scope.oitems = data;
  $scope.items = data;
}
setItems();
function setThing () {
    var dat = {name:'test', id: 12}; //data returned from service
  $scope.othing = dat;
  $scope.name = dat.name;
  $scope.id = dat.id;
  $scope.thing = dat;
}
setThing();


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have an object, `$scope.thing`, and what is supposed to be the original copy `$scope.othing`

This is incorrect. Both variables reference the same object. If you want to make a copy use [`angular.copy()`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.copy)

---

As for `$scope.name = dat.name;` .... this will only be assigned once.

Since the values are primitives and not objects, changes to `$scope.name` or `dat.name` will not change the other after this initial assignment is make.

Primitives do not have inheritance the same way objects do

It is not clear what behaviors you are looking for

Comment: the issue was not using angular.copy()

Comment: here's the working example of what i wanted, sorry for the confusion and thanks for the help with angular.copy()    http://jsfiddle.net/Lvc0u55v/1184/

Answer (score 0):

You can change the code in this way.Working code is following link.

```
 $scope.name: {{name.name}}
 $scope.id: {{id.id}} (this works)
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Lvc0u55v/1165/

Comment: actually, that is the opposite functionality that i want. sorry if I was unclear. I want ng-model to only be bound to $scope.thing and $scope.items, I want $scope.oitems and $scope.othing to hold the values of the original values from the data service. The way that $scope.name and $scope.id had